# Is it possible to get a reference to a dictionary item in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm implementing a cache on a function that gets called hundreds of millions of times. Cache size is tens of millions of items.
It is currently implemented using a `Dictionary`, and lookups in it take a significant amount of time.

Is it possible to get a reference to the whole pair in the `Dictionary`, not just the value, so I can check if a value exists, check it (and, possibly, update it) if it does using a single lookup?

Currently, I have something like this:

```
int val;
if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out val))
    if (val < newVal) cache[key] = newVal;
    else return val;
else
    cache.Add(key, newVal);
```

I would like to get this:

```
Pair pair = cache.GetPair(key);
if (pair != null)
    if (pair.Value < newVal) pair.Value = newVal;
    else return pair.Value;
else
    cache.Add(key, newVal);
```

If there is an alternative data structure that allows this, I'd be glad to hear about it too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "lookups in it take a significant amount of time." Really? What is "a significant amount of time"? Seconds? Milliseconds? Microseconds? Are you sure that you implemented `GetHashCode` and `Equals` correctly? Can you post your code?

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is immutable, so this wouldn't work. Also, dictionary lookups should be O(1).. If it's really taking a long time, something is wrong.

Comment: A single lookup is O(1) and is fast. But millions of lookups have a significant aggregate cost. The usual premature-optimization warnings do not apply here.

Comment: @usr I read "lookups in it take a significant amount of time" as meaning "each lookup" takes time, but perhaps that's not what OP meant. I can certainly see millions of lookups making this worth optimizing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard sorry for being unclear. Single lookup is fast, but there are lots of them and cutting them almost by half would help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is inspired by Mare Infinitus' answer. Assuming your `cache` variable is now a `Dictionary<string, int>` you might change it into a `Dictionary<string, MutableInt32>` where `MutableInt32` is written like this:

```
// wraps an int that may change
class MutableInt32
{
  public int Value;
}
```

Then you could change your code to

```
MutableInt32 val;
if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out val))
  if (val.Value < newVal) val.Value = newVal;
  else ...
```

Comment: of course, with the specified scenario a single mutableInt is enough! but there is already an accepted answer :(

Comment: @MareInfinitus Stack Overflow appreciate our new answers even though one answer was accepted already, I guess. I see really no need to hold an extra copy of the key in the mutable wrapper class. That's why I sent my own answer. It's impossible to change the key in any case, because its hash code is already stored in the `Dictionary<,>`. The `Dictionary<,>` would be corrupted if the **key** changed!

Comment: and i like your idea, so i voted it up! :) holding an extra MutableTuple is just overkill, you are right.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect to get anything except "it isn't possible without manually writing a dictionary", as `usr` suggested, to be honest) This solution actually halved the number of lookups (in the edge case where all lookups are hits) and didn't increase memory consumption at all, since dictionary allocates memory in blocks, and string keys take up enough space that the difference in value sizes doesn't matter. I'll be sure to upvote you and @MareInfinitus for creative thinking as soon as I get enough rep to do that)

Comment: @SanD The important thing here is that the wrapper type (1) is a reference type (`class`), and (2) is mutable. Because of (1), the `Dictionary<,>` holds an "arrow" (reference) to the object. When you look up, your are given another arrow **to the same object**. Then you can change that object (because of (2)), and because both arrows point to the same instance, there's no need to update the `Dictionary<,>`. Actually, instead of the `MutableInt32` class you could also use an `int[]` with just one element (`Length==1`). So it's a 1-tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good in that it *will* cut in half the number of hash-and-find-bucket operations inside the Dictionary. I have benchmarked such stuff myself and Dictionary is not as fast as people think.

Unfortunately, the built-in dictionary does not support this. Not even a workaround.

You can implement your own hashtable and do this yourself. Legal issues aside, you can start with the implementation of Dictionary and add an GetAndUpdateOrCreate method.

Comment: perhaps an own implementation of IDictionary will then do the job? If you have that much pairs, an own bucket sort algorithm can be faster than an generic one.

Comment: That's a good idea. You can get the JIT to do a little better job by hard-coding the type parameters (instead of building a generic dictionary). Andy maybe get rid of the modulo operation and instead use a power-of-two table size so you can use an and-bitmask to calculate the slot index.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course store Pairs in an dictionary!

```
public class KeyValueTuple
{
    private string key;
    private int value;

    public KeyValueTuple(string key, int value)
    { 
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class BigDataCache
{
    private Dictionary<string, KeyValueTuple> cache;

    public BigDataCache()
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<string, KeyValueTuple>();

        cache.Add("entry1", new KeyValueTuple("entry1", 1));
        cache.Add("entry2", new KeyValueTuple("entry2", 2));
        cache.Add("entry3", new KeyValueTuple("entry3", 3));
    }

    public KeyValueTuple GetTuple(string key)
    {
        KeyValueTuple value = null;

        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    BigDataCache d = new BigDataCache();

    var value1 = d.GetTuple("entry1");
    var value2 = d.GetTuple("entryNotValid");
}
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so I don't see where the big speedup is here. Replacing Tuple with a mutable structure might serve OPs needs.

Comment: That would also increase the Dictionary size considerably, as values are just ints, and keys are strings (the cache already takes up gigabytes of RAM, so this is a problem). But that's definitely a nice approach)

Comment: many excuses here from me! did not see that tuple is immutable.

Comment: @spender Yeah, interesting. But shouldn't it be a mutable reference type (`class`). It would only have to be a 1-tuple, but mutable. Like `class MutableValue { public int Value; }`. Then he could use a `Dictionary<string, MutableValue>`.